# Looking for circuit diagrams of current mobile phone chargers

Tags: charger, ac-dc

I am writing an investigation into how a mobile phone charger works and I'm required to break down the internals with a block diagram with component explanations. To help get me on track I'm looking for a circuit diagram of any recent mobile phone chargers in use and/or if anyone knows of any good in-depth sources for this kind of information that could be useful, would be greatly appreciated.

I welcome all feedback, looking forward to hearing your answers.

Comment: By charger do you mean the thing that plugs into the wall and provides power to the phone, or the chip in the phone that takes the voltage from the wall adapter and controls the voltage and current to the battery in order to safely charge the battery?  I ask because many people call the AC adapter a "charger".

Comment: Google is your friend.  Please do your own initial research and then come back asking for help with what you have already discovered.

Comment: @JohnD, I am wondering the same thing. But I do notice that one of the tags is AC-DC.

Comment: Apologies for not specifying, my question refers to the adapter that plugs in the wall.

Comment: Google has been my enemy for a while, I find it really time consuming. Finding a credible source with relevant off the cuff wisdom has taken me precious hours of fruitless rummaging.

Comment: However Dwayne, I will review my search strategy. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Dwayne says should be noted. Image search is an immensely powerful tool for this. eg try [**lithium ion charger schematic**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=lithium+ion+charger+schematic&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=1075&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=_MDyVOyjEqHHmAX3iYGYDA&ved=0CBsQsAQ)

BUT, here is a source that is often useful that Googling may not easily uncover.

Digikey (amongst others) has an utterly vast quantity of stock and a range of components beyond reasonable belief. They also have a very good parametric and keyword search engine that allows you to use them as a technical reference library. (I also even but stuff from them occasionally :-).)

Here is the result of a Digikey search for - lithium ion charger, followed by selecting the "Evaluation and Demonstration Boards and Kits" subset.

This gives 100++ evaluation and development kits - many are relevant to your query and many have links to manual wit full circuit.

[**Digikey - Evaluation and Demonstration Boards and Kits - Lithium Ion Charger**](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/programmers-development-systems/evaluation-and-demonstration-boards-and-kits/2622039?k=lithium%20ion%20charger)

Here's one example [MCP1631HV Multi-Chemistry Battery Charger Reference Design](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51791a.pdf)

Also:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01137A.pdf
http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7801.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluu439a/sluu439a.pdf

and many more.